# Authentication and RedirectFromLoginPage doesnt work properly asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Im trying to make my Homepage secured to visit pages without Login and have read a lot about Authentication/Authorization.

First problem is that i still can visit my home.aspx for example even if havent done the Login. Ive set the authorization to deny users but it still works.

Second Problem is that i put a defualtUrl to Hom because i want the user to be redirected to that page after correct Login but it still searches for the /defualt page....

Hope someone can help me.

Here is some code..

Login + code behind

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <br />

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Benutzer:</td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="Username" runat="server" Width="120px" /></td>
    <td>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
        ControlToValidate="Username"
        Display="Dynamic" 
        ErrorMessage="Bitte Benutzer eingeben" 
        runat="server" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Passwort:</td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="Password" TextMode="Password" 
         runat="server" Width="120px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" 
        ControlToValidate="Password"
        ErrorMessage="Bitte Passwort eingeben" 
        runat="server" />
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" Text="Einloggen" 
   runat="server" />
<p>
  <asp:Label ID="Msg" ForeColor="red" runat="server" />
</p>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataLayer.DataConnector dat = new DataLayer.DataConnector("Provider=SQLOLEDB; data source=rzwsrv010;database=event;user ID=event;password=event; Persist Security Info=False");
         DataTable dt = dat.DataSelect("select UserID from login where Username = '" + Username.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "' and Password = '" + Password.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "'");
         if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
         {
             FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Username.Text, false);
         }
         else
         {
             Msg.Text = "Falsche Benutzer oder Passwort";
         }

    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataLayer.DataConnector dat = new DataLayer.DataConnector("Provider=SQLOLEDB; data source=rzwsrv010;database=event;user ID=event;password=event; Persist Security Info=False");
         DataTable dt = dat.DataSelect("select UserID from login where Username = '" + Username.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "' and Password = '" + Password.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "'");
         if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
         {
             FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Username.Text, false);
         }
         else
         {
             Msg.Text = "Falsche Benutzer oder Passwort";
         }

    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: Are you able to post the relevant parts of your web.config

Comment: Iv'e tried but it stands that the code is not correct formatted or something.

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl ="Home.aspx">
          
        </forms >
      </authentication>

      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>

Comment: Have you created the aspnet database and set the membership section in your web.config?

Comment: Nope im using a SQL Server db and want to give the users from my db table entrance to the website

Answer (score 0):

to use the microsoft security You have to have the membership bits in your config I believe. The easiest way to do the authentication is to run aspnet_regsql.exe against the database where you want your users. This will create the tables etc that work by default with the microsoft security. This might not be how you want to implement it but it does work.

The aspnet_regsql is inside the microsoft.net folders such as

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319



<connectionStrings>
<add name="Platform" connectionString="Data Source=[server];Initial Catalog=[database];Persist Security Info=True;User ID=[login];Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="/Home.aspx" timeout="240" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>

<membership defaultProvider="Provider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="Provider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="Platform" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```